# Octave input arguments to function as cell array

Tags: matlab, function, octave, cell-array, multiple-arguments

I want to input arguments to an octave function as a cell array:

```
function x = myfunc(a_string, an_int)
  printf("a string: %s\n", a_string);
  printf("an int: %d\n", an_int);
end

myfunc("a", 1);
b = {"a", 1};
myfunc(b); % should do the same thing as myfunc("a", 1)
```

Is there any way to do this easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `{:}` indexing to expand the contents of the cell array out into multiple inputs to your function. The `{:}` indexing creates a comma separated list which behaves just as multiple inputs.

```
myfunc(b{:})
```